How to calculate resistors on PCB for white LEDs
Thanks for closing my post... once again.
Instead of helping it gets instantly closed.
I somewhat got the answer thanks to AnalogKid's answer! I dont get how he calculated the 2mA but thanks to his calculations I could reverse engineer it and lowered the resistors. Now more current can flow and the LEDs light up :)
I would really like to know how you calculated that tho.
I am trying to switch the red LEDs on a PCB to white ones. It took ages to trace the circuit and 99% I found the corresponding resistors. There are 22 LEDs and I found 11 resistors. I know I have to decrease the number of resistance since the white LEDs have a higher Vf. I am extremely confused how to calculate this, since the resistors are all connected parallel and series. Is there any way to know what I should replace these with.


(Resistors back side of the board, LEDs are on the front side.
Input Voltage: 12V, Total LEDs connected: 22 (Unsure if all are in series or also parallel) Unlikely all in series, Each red LED draws about 20 mA at 1.8 V, the new white ones draw 20 mA at 2.5 V.
I don't understand how to even draw a schematic from the image. Hard to understand what is parallel and what is not when looking at the SMDs

Difficult to answer without the full schematic and the LED datasheets. It all comes down the LEDs themselves, required brightness levels, and maybe some other factors. If the original red ones are driven with, say, 5 mA then this doesn't mean that the white ones should be driven with 5 mA as well. Depending on the specific white LED you want to put, the brightness requirement (if any) may not be met so you may want to increase the drive current but this might be limited by something else. So, like I said, difficult to answer without knowing the details.

Welcome! Try to sketch a schematic of the resistors and the LEDs. Click on Edit and the schematic symbol and you can draw it there. What drive voltage did you measure before the resistors?

What's the supply voltage, how many LEDs in series? I think I already mentioned in your previous (now closed) question that it might be impossible to change the red LEDs to white unless you know what is driving them and how.

Tip: Use the editor toolbar CircuitLab button to draw your schematic and use the Save and Insert button to insert a PNG of the schematic into the post along with an edit link. There's no need for a CircuitLab account. No screengrab. No grid. It also means that others can copy and paste your schematic for further editing.
Double-click to edit component properties. 'H' and 'V' to flip. 'R' to rotate. 'N' for a node or external connection.

You need to show where the LEDs get connected. Not all of those resistors maybe LED current-limiting resistors. Especially with those values.

A schematic is critical. It might be the case that there is 1 resistor for every 2 LEDs. This is a way of getting double-duty out of the LED current. It is more efficient, and reduces the power dissipation in the resistors.
The resistor values seem a bit high for a 12 V system. 302 is the code for a 3 kΩ, 5% resistor. 4701 could be 4.7 kΩ, 1%. That is not a standard E-96 value, but some manufacturers make 1% versions of the 5% values. Still, that is just over 2 mA for one LED, or 1.7 mA for 2 red LEDs in series.

To be clear, "It might be the case that there is 1 resistor for every two series-connected LEDs."

I dont know how you calculated that, but could lead to the right direction. The original LEDs were low current red PLCC2 leds, only needing 2mA to turn on as far as i know.

We would need a schematic to give a definitive answer. The schematic should show the power voltage (e.g., 12 V, 5 V, or whatever) so that we can establish if there is enough headroom to drive white LEDs.
The series and parallel resistors may be to spread the heat dissipation over several components to keep within their rated power specifications.

Thanks a lot! Sadly i dont understand how to make a schematic out of it and neither do i have one :( new to this, cant figure out what is parallel and series by looking at the board

@TJCDE Follow the traces on the board and use a multimeter to find out which via goes where.
